# Binary Search: Infinite Loop

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search

I am trying to solve a binary search problem, however, I keep getting an infinite loop, since the values of `lo` `hi` and `mid` do not change as they suppose to.  I am trying to search for a minimum mid value where function `count_lines(mid,k) >= n`. I have spent hours debugging this code but I still couldn't figure out what is wrong with the values of `lo` `hi` and `mid`. Could someone please look at my code and show me why this happen? Many thanks!

Failed testing case where: `n=9` `k=2`
Here is my code:

```
   def count_lines(v,k):
   ...
   ...
   return count_lines #count_lines is an integer` 


   def binarySearch_v(n, k):
   lo = 0
   hi = n
   mid = (lo + hi)//2
   while (lo <= hi):
     if (count_lines(mid, k) < n):
        lo = mid
     elif (count_lines(mid, k) > n):
        hi = mid
     elif (count_lines(mid, k) >= n and count_lines(mid-1, k) < n):
        return mid
     mid = (lo + hi) // 2

    def main():
      print(binarySearch_v(n,k)) # Failed at n=9 & k=2
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38258457/where-is-the-mistake-in-my-code-to-perform-binary-search/38258974#38258974

Answer (score 2):

Here's your termination condition:

```
while (lo <= hi):
```

And here's where `lo` and `hi` can possibly change values:

```
lo = mid
...
hi = mid
```

The logical conclusion is that, if this code loops enough times, you'll end up with `lo == hi`. `mid` will then be set to the average of the two, which is equal to both of them, and that's where all three variables will stay. And as such, the loop *will not terminate*. There are two possible solutions: either change the way you're reassigning `lo` or `hi`, or change the termination condition to `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I see what you are saying. I have tried to change the terminate condition from <= to < as you suggested and unfortunately I still got an infinite loop. It seems weird to me that the value of `mid` does not change even when I reassign the value of mid with new low and new high. I have attached a screenshot of my output for your view. Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Seems that your code is always taking the `"GOT HERE"` branch of those if statements. I advise debugging by figuring out *why* it's always taking that branch, and what it should be doing instead.

Comment: I will look into that. Thanks!